# python parsing selected part of text file

Tags: python

I am trying a program to print the selected part of the text from a text file :text.txt

txt.txt contains:

```
tickme 1.1(no.3)
lesson1-bases
lesson2-advancedfurther
para:using the dsp signals are sened via a transmitter to conver to analong signals and gets the output in the form of digital signal

tickme 2.2(no.4)
lesson1-basics2
lesson2-advanced4
para:using the DIGITAL signals are sened via a transmitter to conver to analong signals and gets the output in the form of digital signal

tickme 3.3(no.5)
lesson1-bas
lesson2-adv
para:using the dsp signals are sened via a transmitter to conver to analong signals and gets the output in the form of digital signal
```

Here it consists of 3 tick me but i wanted to select a particular tickme 2.2(no.4) where i have to parse the text before start of tickme 3.3(no.5)

So, if DIGITAL is in para,then it has to print leason1,since it cause ambiguity i wanted to select range of text file

output:

```
lesson1-basics2
```

Since it has lesson 1 common for all tick me,**i need to select specific area to parse between tickme2.2(no.4) to tickme 3.3(no.5)** Is there a way to get range for a specific area and parse?

program:it doesnot select specific range

```
searchstring=""
with open('text.txt','r') as file:

    for line in file:
        if 'tickme' in line:
            searchstring=line
        if searchstring!='':
            if 'DIGITAL' in line:
                print searchstring
                print line
```

Please help ! answers would be appreciated

Comment: What should the range be specified by? For example from the first finding of `tickme2.2` to the next occurence of `tickme`? In any case, this information must be somewhere in your program (or given as an argument from `sys.argv`)

Comment: if expected output is always two lines before line with `DIGITAL` than read line by line searching `DIGITAL` but alway keep in memory two previous lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the range as function arguments. Then you can save all the lines within that range in a list , and use that list of lines for further parsing.

```
#Function to accept file name, start line of range, end line of range
#Returns a list of lines within that range 
def select_range(filename, start_range, end_range):
f = open(filename, 'r')
selected_lines=[]
start=0
for line in f:
    if start_range in line:
        start=1
    if end_range in line:
        start=0
        return selected_lines
    if start==1:
        selected_lines.append(line)
return selected_lines
```

`lines=select_range("tickme.txt","tickme 2.2(no.4)","tickme 3.3(no.5)")
print lines`

Answer (score 0):

Split the file into batches like so:

```
with open('txt.txt') as f:
    batches = []

    t = []
    for l in line:
        if 'tickme' in l:
            # Start a new bactch after saving the previous batch 
            if t: batches.apend(t)
            t = [l.strip()]
        else:
            if len(l.strip()) > 1: t.append(l.strip())
```

Then things become much easier ...